# Git asks for password everytime when I push ,I used ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I have configured SSH in my machine and my github. but git asks for password everytime when I push.

I find some answers, check the config file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and closed the  `passwordAuthentication`, and run `service ssh restart`,
but it's not work. I don't know why? How to solve this question?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to use a cert with passphase to push to git from your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to githubs [adding an SSH key to git on linux](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-linux).

The main part you might be missing from the instructions above is to add your local key to ssh-agent `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` where `id_rsa` is the name of your key file. If you have cloned/setup your local repo instance to use `ssh://...` as Sanjit outlined and you have your key pair in the right place you should be asked for the passphase on a cert that was created with one.

It is also worth checking you have added the SSH key to github correctly.

1. log in to github.com.
2. Right click on your profile pic and select settings.
3. In the sidebar select `SSH and GPG keys`. (or enter this url https://github.com/settings/keys)
4. You will see a list of keys you have added for each host which should include the one you are trying to use.
5. If you cert is not in the list you can add it by selecting `New SSH key`.

(see https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

To check the origin path is using SSH run `git remote -v` from within the repo directory which will show you the fetch and push paths. 
To change the orgin to SSH use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git` which can be found in githubs article on [changing a remotes url](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh).

Your sshd config changes may not have been required.

Comment: Thanks very much,I've resolved.I didn't add my local key to ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the SSH one not the https or git one.
Example : `ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git`

not

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
git://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: Yes,I use ssh.sorry,I just described the inaccuracy. The problem is that I still want to enter a Passphrase not my github password  everytime when I push

Comment: @lavender it asks for a password because when you generated you ssh key you entered a passphrase. If you don't want to enter a password every time you push/pull then generate a ssh key without passphrase.